# When using WP and Gatsby is it possible to overwrite some auto-generated pages with local custom ones?

Tags: wordpress, gatsby, headless-cms

Is it possible to ignore a specific route(s) during createPage generation, and instead have a page in the `src/pages/` directory take precedence?   e.g.  I have a route with a number of subpages e.g `parent/child1`,   `parent/child2`  etc.  However, I'm hoping to be able to create a custom page for `parent/` in the `src/pages` directory which would essentially overwrite the auto-generated content from WordPress.

**Snippet from gatsby-node.js:**

```
allWordpressPage.edges.forEach(edge => {
if (edge.node.status === 'publish') {
  createPage({
    path: edge.node.link,
    component: slash(pageTemplate),
    context: {
      id: edge.node.id,
      parent: edge.node.wordpress_parent,
      wpId: edge.node.wordpress_id,
    },
  });
 }
});
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this by just checking for against the appropriate pathname and essentially skipping createPage in that case:

`if (edge.node.status === 'publish' && edge.node.link !== 'PATH_NAME_HERE') {`

The file specified in `src/pages/` will now be used instead.